# Isolation level use cases in real world

Tags: spring, database, transactions, spring-transactions

I've gone through multiple tutorials and articles about different isolation levels. I understood the concept, but I don't understand the real world scenario where to use which level. Are there any simple use cases where they can be demonstrated? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isolation levels are not a Spring concept - spring only supports it, this is a database concept. You need to work with databases to understand why dirty reads are a problem and why therefore Read Committed Isolation level is necessary etc. I can recommend you articles but without practical experience with databases you will have hard time getting it.

If you do want to understand the topic, install an Oracle database and play with setting different isolation levels and seeing what effects does that make if you for example open 2 sessions with 2 SQLPlus Windows and try to update/read same rows.

Comment: Thanks Asgarov. I was referring to the use cases when these levels should be used.

Comment: General answer: databases are used by multiple clients in real time concurrently. That means same rows can be modified/read concurrently. That is why it is important to protect these rows via setting isolation levels. The higher the isolation level the higher is the security but the slower does the database get. Therefore you find an acceptable to your business level that provides enough security and use that.

Comment: Read uncommitted doesn't make sense, then why did they have introduced this level? This question keep revolving in my mind always. Could you please explain?

Comment: Read uncommitted wasn't invented it is the lowest isolation level because it is what's left if you remove all the security measurements that other levels introduce. That is like asking why did we bother inventing machine code if we could just program in Java.

Comment: So, do you find any use cases for read uncommitted?

Comment: If you don't have concurrency (single user) in your database you can use read uncommitted.